# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on c# EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

Sometime I get this error message when i run my project in Hosting.There is no problem on the local server. Sometimes this error comes up on the server, sometimes it works without any problems. I could not find the cause of the problem. Is it giving an error when creating a database instance? I'm using EF 6. Could it be a problem with the version?

https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screen-Shot-2022-05-06-at-12.43.10.png

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //var getNotes = (_noteManager.ListQueryable().Where(x => x.IsDraft == false && x.IsApproved == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).Take(10).ToList());
            return View(getNotes);
        }
```

Comment: So many possibilities are there. I think you should put some reproducible code if you want to get better help.

Answer (score 0):

When i get this error i refresh browser and i can join website without problem.But another times i get again this error and i should refresh again.İts very weird